# How to disable SSL/TLS Diffie-Hellman keys less that 2048 bits

Tags: linux, ssl

I want to disable Diffie-Hellman key exchange with keys shorter than 2048 bits because I have a Weak SSL/TLS Key Exchange vulnerability alert.

As a solution, the tool itself tells me the following:

```
Change the SSL/TLS server configuration to only allow strong key exchanges. Key exchanges used on the server should provide at least 112 bits of security, so the minimum key size to not flag this QID should be:  
2048 bit key size for Diffie Hellman (DH) or RSA key exchanges  
224 bit key size for Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman (EDCH) key exchanges.
```

From what I have found, I see that modifying the following line in the java.security file would fix the error

> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES,
> MD5withRSA, 
> DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, 
> include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

to

> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES,
> MD5withRSA, 
> DH keySize < 2048, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, 
> include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

Should I make any other modifications because I have read in some forums that modifying that line still causes the vulnerability to appear?

Comment: Where in the OS? In Nginx? In Apache?

Comment: the operating system is RHEL 8.2

Comment: Where did that alert came from and can you see what configuration the alert was triggered on. By disabling this you could break a workload or service using it. So make sure you exactly know what is running on the server. For making a secure ssl config also check out https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=nginx&version=1.17.7&config=modern&openssl=1.1.1k&guideline=5.7

Comment: you'll need to modify the SSL/TLS server configuration, typically found in the configuration file of your web server (e.g., Apache or Nginx).

Answer (score 0):

Encryption/cryptographic settings in Linux are application specific and there is not really a single system wide setting that allows you to adjust crypto settings for all applications, servers and services.

The RHEL [`update-crypto-policies`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening) command comes closest but with the default policies like for example `update-crypto-policies --set FUTURE` it does not provide the granularity to adjust a single setting without creating your own and your  applications may not even have a crypto policy.

Comment: Why Future? That requires at least 3072 instead of 2048. The RSA keys and Diffie-Hellman parameters are accepted if they are at least 3072 bits long.